# Do i need to dispose a form after I am done using it?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I know that C# is an automatic garbage collection language, but will I notice a difference if I dispose a form? For example:

```
SettingsDialog dialog;
private void settingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dialog = new SettingsDialog();
    dialog.ShowDialog();
    dialog.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(dialog_FormClosed);
}
void dialog_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    dialog.Dispose();
}
```

Or should I leave it as:

```
private void settingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SettingsDialog dialog = new SettingsDialog();
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

Also, what if SettingsDialog consumes large amounts of memory? Will this make a difference?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The *contract* of *anything* that implements IDisposable dictates that the Dispose *will* be called by the "owner" in correctly written code. It doesn't matter if the Dispose implementation currently does nothing. It doesn't matter if the finalizer may [eventually] do the same stuff as Dispose. Not invoking Dispose (directly or indirectly) as needed violates the contract. (This is why it is a breaking change to add or remove the IDisposable interface.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
using(SettingsDialog dialog = new SettingsDialog())
{
    dialog.ShowDialog();
}
```

this will Dispose `dialog` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is to always `Dispose()` instances of types that implement the `IDisposable` interface.  The easiest way to do that in a resource-proctective way is employing the `using` statement as per [Petr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/735446/petr-abdulin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734879/do-i-need-to-dispose-a-form-after-i-am-done-using-it/7734890#7734890).

Waiting for the finalizer, while not detrimental in many cases, will bite you in some cases since you don't know when it will occur (non-deterministic).

Best stick with disposing when you're done.

Comment: Finalize in this case will miss some important things like Destroying the handle, etc.